# Apache Beam Pipeline beam.io.ReadFromText(data_path) is 10 times slower than reading test

Tags: tensorflow, apache-beam

I am now trying to run a job in Google Cloud where the input dataset is stored as Google Object Storage. Both Compute Engine and Object storage are in the same region.

The problem is that when I use `time gsutil cat gs://my-bucket-name/my-dataset.txt > /dev/null`  to test the reading speed of my dataset, it turns out to be 1.3 Gbit/s. This is okay. But when I run the following code snippet (I only keep two basic operators to test the reading speed in DataFlowRunner), it turns out to be 10 times slower. The size of the dataset is about 10GB and it takes 15 mins to finish this pipeline.

```
 with beam.Pipeline(args.runner, options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    with tft_beam.Context(temp_dir=args.temp_dir):
      processed_lines = (
          pipeline
          | beam.io.ReadFromText(data_path)
          | "CountLines" >> beam.combiners.Count.Globally()
          )
```

When I use htop to monitor the resource usage, the utilization of CPU is nearly 0 and only one thread is actively running.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/recommendation/ranking/preprocessing/criteo_preprocess.py. The complete script is in Tensorflow Git Repo.

- OS Platform and Distribution : Linux 6.1.0-18-cloud-amd64 x86_64
- TensorFlow version: 2.15.0
- Python version: 3.9.2
- I have tried to partition the input dataset to be 32 or 64 sub-files and there is no improvement.
- What I expect is that the reading speed can reach 1.3 Gbit/s